# Xamarin forms: Pop up page not closing when click device back button

Tags: xamarin.forms, popup, nuget-package

I am using `Rg.Plugins.Popup` NuGet package for showing pop up page. **When clicking the android device back button the pop-up page is not hiding**, it only closes the content pages. I am working on a `.Net standard project`.

**Versions:**

Rg.Plugins.Popup - 1.1.5.180

Xamarin Forms - 3.3.0.967583

**Pop-up Page Codes**

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}

protected override bool OnBackgroundClicked()
{
    return base.OnBackgroundClicked();
}
```

BackgroundClicked closing the pop-up page, but the device back button pressed not closing the pop-up page.

Comment: Go through this https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Getting-started#android-back-button

Comment: Please post it as your answer, it solved the issue

Comment: public override async void OnBackPressed()
        {
            if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed))
            {
                await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
            }
        }

Comment: I updated in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android back button issues handle on 'OnBackPressed',

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed(base.OnBackPressed))
    {
        // Do something if there are some pages in the `PopupStack`
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something if there are not any pages in the `PopupStack`
    }
}
```